# Performance issues in Python for small loops over simple array look-ups

Tags: python, c++, arrays, performance

Why are simple loops and/or simple array look-ups so slow in Python?

Specifically, Python (using `pypy`) is approximately 9 times slower than C++ (with `-O2`) in the following example.  What is the technical reason that explains the performance penalty?  Is it the implementation of Python loops in machine code?  differences in the optimizations used by the compilers? the memory management?  or something else?

The Python code:

```
# File: timing.py
import sys
T = [ \
        [ 0, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8,19,20, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22,19,20,21,22,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,], \
        [ 9, 7,10, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7,23, 7, 7, 1,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9,10,30,31, 7, 9,10,30,31, 7,23, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,30,31,30,31,], \
        [ 7, 7, 2,11,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,11,12,24,25,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,26,27,32, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7,37,38,], \
        [13, 7,14, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7,28, 7, 7, 3,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,13,14,33,34, 7,13,14,33,34, 7,28, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,33,34,33,34,], \
        [15, 7,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [17, 7,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [19, 7,20, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7,29, 7, 7, 6,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,19,20,35,36, 7,19,20,35,36, 7,29, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,35,36,35,36,], \
        [ 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [21, 7,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 9, 1, 7, 7, 7,23, 1, 7,23, 9,10, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 9,10,30,31,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23,30,31, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,10, 1,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1,23, 9,10,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9,10,30,31,23, 7, 7, 7,23,30,31, 7, 7,30,31,], \
        [24, 7,25, 7, 7, 7,11, 7,32, 7, 7,11,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,37,38, 7,24,25,37,38, 7,32, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,37,38,37,38,], \
        [26, 7,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [13, 3, 7, 7, 7,28, 3, 7,28,13,14, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34,13,14,33,34,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28,33,34, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,14, 3,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3,28,13,14,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,13,14,33,34,28, 7, 7, 7,28,33,34, 7, 7,33,34,], \
        [15, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,16, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [17, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,18, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [19, 6, 7, 7, 7,29, 6, 7,29,19,20, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36,19,20,35,36,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,20, 6,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6,29,19,20,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,19,20,35,36,29, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7,35,36,], \
        [21, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,22, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [30, 7,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [24,11, 7, 7, 7,32,11, 7,32,24,25, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38,24,25,37,38,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,25,11,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,11,32,24,25,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,37,38,32, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7,37,38,], \
        [26, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,27, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [33, 7,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [35, 7,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [30, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,31, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [37, 7,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [33, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,34, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [35, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,36, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [37, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
        [ 7, 7,38, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,], \
            ]

M = range(39)
idempotents = [0,2,6,7,8,9,11,12,14,16,17,19,21,25,27]
omega = [0,7,2,7,7,7,6,7,8,9,7,11,12,7,14,7,16,17,7,19,7,21,7,7,7,25,7,27,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]

def check():
    for e in idempotents:
        for x in M:
            ex = T[e][x]
            for s in M:
                es = T[e][s]
                for f in idempotents:
                    exf = T[ex][f]
                    esf = T[es][f]
                    for y in M:
                        exfy = omega[T[exf][y]]
                        for t in M:
                            tesf = omega[T[t][esf]]
                            if T[T[exfy][exf]][tesf] != T[T[exfy][esf]][tesf]:
                                return 0
    return 1
sys.exit(check())
```

The C++ code (requires C++11 because of the new array initialization and iteration syntax):

```
// File: timing.cc
// Compile via 'g++ -std=c++11 -O2 timing.cc'
// Run via 'time ./a.out'
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

int main(int, char **) {
  const size_t N = 39;
  typedef unsigned element_t;
  const std::vector<std::vector<element_t>> T{{
     {{ 0, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8,19,20, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22,19,20,21,22,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 9, 7,10, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7,23, 7, 7, 1,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9,10,30,31, 7, 9,10,30,31, 7,23, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,30,31,30,31,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7, 2,11,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,11,12,24,25,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,26,27,32, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7,37,38,}}, 
     {{13, 7,14, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7,28, 7, 7, 3,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,13,14,33,34, 7,13,14,33,34, 7,28, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,33,34,33,34,}}, 
     {{15, 7,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{17, 7,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{19, 7,20, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7,29, 7, 7, 6,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,19,20,35,36, 7,19,20,35,36, 7,29, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,35,36,35,36,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{21, 7,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 9, 1, 7, 7, 7,23, 1, 7,23, 9,10, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 9,10,30,31,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23,30,31, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,10, 1,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1,23, 9,10,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9,10,30,31,23, 7, 7, 7,23,30,31, 7, 7,30,31,}}, 
     {{24, 7,25, 7, 7, 7,11, 7,32, 7, 7,11,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,37,38, 7,24,25,37,38, 7,32, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,37,38,37,38,}}, 
     {{26, 7,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{13, 3, 7, 7, 7,28, 3, 7,28,13,14, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34,13,14,33,34,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28,33,34, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,14, 3,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3,28,13,14,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,13,14,33,34,28, 7, 7, 7,28,33,34, 7, 7,33,34,}}, 
     {{15, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,16, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,15,16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{17, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,18, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,17,18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{19, 6, 7, 7, 7,29, 6, 7,29,19,20, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36,19,20,35,36,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,20, 6,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6,29,19,20,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,19,20,35,36,29, 7, 7, 7,29,35,36, 7, 7,35,36,}}, 
     {{21, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,22, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,21,22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{30, 7,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{24,11, 7, 7, 7,32,11, 7,32,24,25, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38,24,25,37,38,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,25,11,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,11,32,24,25,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,24,25,37,38,32, 7, 7, 7,32,37,38, 7, 7,37,38,}}, 
     {{26, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,27, 7,12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,12, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,26,27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{33, 7,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{35, 7,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{30, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,31, 7,23, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,23, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,30,31, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{37, 7,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{33, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,34, 7,28, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,28, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,33,34, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{35, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,36, 7,29, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,29, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,35,36, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{37, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
     {{ 7, 7,38, 7,32, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,32, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,37,38, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,}}, 
  }};

  const std::vector<element_t> idempotents{{0,2,6,7,8,9,11,12,14,16,17,19,21,25,27}};
  const std::vector<element_t> omega{{0,7,2,7,7,7,6,7,8,9,7,11,12,7,14,7,16,17,7,19,7,21,7,7,7,25,7,27,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7}};

  element_t ex, es, exf, esf, exfy, tesf;
  for(auto e: idempotents) {
    for(size_t x = 0; x < N; ++x) {
      ex = T[e][x];
      for(size_t s = 0; s < N; ++s) {
        es = T[e][s];
        for(auto f: idempotents) {
          exf = T[ex][f];
          esf = T[es][f];
          for(size_t y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
            exfy = omega[T[exf][y]];
            for(size_t t = 0; t < N; ++t) {
              tesf = omega[T[t][esf]];
              if(T[T[exfy][exf]][tesf] != T[T[exfy][esf]][tesf])
                return 0;
            }}}}}}
  return 1;
}
```

*(Don't ask for details about what the code does.  Roughly speaking, a decision procedure in the context of algebraic formal language theory is implemented; the code verifies an identity on the monoid given by the multiplication table `T`.  In particular, the code is not a contrived example but a real-world application.  Of course, one can argue about "applications" in the context of formal language theory.)*

## Timing results

With the code as above the user CPU running times on my machine are as follows:

- `time pypy timing.py` outputs `0m9.329s`
- `time python timing.py` outputs `2m18.389s`
- `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 timing.cc && time ./a.out` outputs `0m1.064s`

### Edit

- For a fairer comparison I did some optimizations that `g++` seems to incorporate automatically. I re-ordered the loops and moved the variable assignments as far outward as possible (as suggested by the comments).  This yields a speedup factor for `pypy` of about 2.5 and for `python` of about 2.
- Also for fairness, I used the dynamic-sized `std::vector` instead of the constant-sized `std::array`.
- I deleted the asides as to why numpy is slower (the comments indicate that I did not use it correctly) and why executing the loops in the main part of the script is slower (it is known that Python is faster with local variables than with global variables; the comments give references for this).
- I am aware of the fact that C++ and Python have different scopes. I also know that C++ is compiled, whereas Python is normally interpreted (which is why I used `pypy`). I want to know the ultimate technical reason as to why `pypy` is so much slower on this specific piece of code. (Using numpy and numba one may be able to attain near-native performance here, but this is not in the spirit of my question, because it shifts virtually all the computation back to C code.)  I clarified my question accordingly.

Comment: what is your numpy implementation? doing normal python for-loops over numpy arrays will be slow. but with numpy you can avoid writing python for-loops and that will speed up your code a lot.

Comment: the additional 7 secs are almost surely due to the fact that python access local variables faster than global variables. See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables)

Comment: An ancient trick is to cache globals in local variables for faster lookups. You're also doing a lot of computation in the innermost loop that can be hoisted outward (`exf`, `esf`, `exfy`) and there's a fair chance that your C++ compiler did that for you. You won't get anywhere near the C++ performance anyway, of course, but it should make a noticable difference.

Comment: I got a improvement from 4 min 53s down to 12 seconds with numba autojit.

Comment: Moving some of the variables out to the outer loops, as suggested by @molbdnilo, decreased it further down to 7 seconds.

Comment: I guess you did keep the loops when switching to numpy. I wonder how fast it is if one uses a proper index notation. e.g. `T[e][x] == T[idempotents]` without loops.

Comment: @usethedeathstar: It's just the code above with `T` wrapped in a numpy array. Could you hint at how to avoid Python-loops in numpy?

@Bort: I don't know that syntax. Maybe you can contribute a modification of the code according to it?

@molbdnilo, @M4rtini: I am aware of the possibility to improve performance by moving variables.  The code is the straightforward excerpt of a larger framework.  Imho it's not fair to move it; if C++ can do it automatically, why can't Python?

Thanks all for the hint with global vs local variables and also for the pointer to numba.

Comment: @Xlea Python and C++ are two entirely different languages that excel in different areas, expecting identical code in both to have the same level of performance is a bit off base. To start with I suggest googling "Why are python loops slow?" for a wealth of information. As for numpy: if you are writing python loops with numpy arrays you are likely writing the code incorrectly. I would recommending reading up on numpy [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.html).

Comment: @Ophion I know that Python and C++ have different scopes. But I'm curious about the technical details that cause this huge difference between (current implementations of) Python and C++, in particular when using a JIT-compiler for Python. Is it the implementation of the loops in machine code? memory management? differences in the optimization applied by the compilers? or something else? I can't find a convincing technical explanation to such *why*-questions.

Comment: @Xlea Pinging you here to say thanks for the [proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39464990/revisions) to my answer elsewhere. I incorporated your code and sprinkled some upvotes over you.

Comment: @tripleee Well, thanks to you for your initial answer elsewhere which helped me a lot. And thanks for the thumbs.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer to numpy and python loops

if you are using numpy correctly you push everything back to C-level again.

### Long answer

How can one do that?

I'll show here a little bit what I meant with my comment and how one avoids unnecessary loops with numpy. Let's have a look at the original code assuming you have put all lists into np.arrays with np.asarray(list).

```
for e in idempotents:
    for x in M:
        ex = T[e][x]
```

This translates directly to:

```
T[idempotents]
```

### **Why is that?**

Numpy arrays can use arrays of indices for indexing. E.g.
`T[0]` returns all columns (actually all following dimensions) of matrix T. So `T[0]==T[0,:]` for 2d arrays. Since you are looping over all idempotents as indices and than over all elements in the columns `T[e][x]`, `T[idempotents]` is identical to these two loops.

For details about it see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

### ex, es

Next is

```
for e in idempotents:
    for x in M:
        ex = T[e][x]
        for s in M:
            es = T[e][s]
```

Since there is no point in redoing the entire loop again, this translates to

```
es=ex
```

because we are using python, the matrix es is not even copied, just referenced.

### exf, esf

I am skipping now some of the for loops in the snippets.

```
for f in idempotents:
    exf = T[ex][f]
    esf = T[es][f]
```

Now you are accessing the outer most index again with the vector of idempotents. So we can do this exactly with numpy in the same way:

```
T[T[idempotents]]
print T[T[idempotents]].shape
>> (15, 39, 39)
```

Now, we have an array of dimension (15, 39, 39), because for each element of the 2d array T[idempotents] you return the element of T. This is basically the third loop.

```
exf = T[T[idempotents]]
esf = exf
```

from here on it gets more complicated and I will skip the rest. It will be along following lines:

```
Ti = T[idempotents]  # T[e][x] == T[e][s] by loop definition
TTi = T[Ti]  # T[T[e][x]]
TTi.shape = -1 , 39  # bring first index back into shape
exf = TTi[:, idempotents]  # T[T[e][x]][f]
esf = exf  # T[T[e][s]][f] == T[T[e][x]][f] by loop definition
Texf = T[exf].ravel()
exfy = omega[Texf]
TTexf = T.T[exf].ravel()  # tesf = omega[T[t][esf]] # since I cannot index fast along t I use the transpose of T
tesf = omega[TTexf]
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It's interesting to see numpy applied, for that a vote up. But as I pointed out in my edit, this is not in the sprit of my question. Moreover, I disagree that the loop over `s` can be dropped by setting `ex = es`. This changes the semantics of the code (in fact, it would trivially `return 1` no matter what `T`).

Comment: The components of the vector es or ex are identical no matter when you do the loops. The semantics is preserved by the order of application as nested indices.The C++ compiler will likely do something like this as well and more. This goes off topic though.

Comment: Got it, you didn't mean in my original code, then?! I probably got confused as you didn't define `ex` in your code. But now I'm curious. You say `T[T[idempotents]]` is three-dimensional, so has size approximately n cubed, where n is the size of `M`. How is this implemented? If this array was actually expanded in memory, this would not be acceptable in my case (remember, this is only a toy example). What happens when a value is assigned to a cell in the matrix?

Comment: It is expanded in memory. Although one could do tricks with unique elements and index matrices to reduce the number of elements. In the long run you are probably better off writing a program which generates the c++ implementation automatically and let the compiler optimization handle the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python interprets its input at runtime, whereas the C++ compiler is able to perform major optimizations, particularly on for-loops with fixed sized arrays.

Some compilers might even compute the entire output of the nested for-loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that Python is typically interpreted, that's why I included timings with `pypy`. I just wonder why optimization for such straightforward loops is so much better for C++. Btw, I edited my question to include timings for the dynamic `std::vector` array type.